# My first rebus!(Inspired by Wordster)

Tags: rebus

This is my first rebus. Inspired by Wordster!

[image: picture 1][image: picture 2]

Comment: A real stumper! :)  I don't even KNOW what image #2 is.  Image #3 could be several things.

Comment: @Wordster ummmm there are only 2 images the wheat and windmill are the same image

Comment: Oh!  Well thanx 4 that!  I'll try again...

Comment: That might help...

Comment: Actually, I thought the clouds were the 2nd item.

Comment: Oh, now it's half a can, hmmmnnn...

Comment: It's a good try, but there is no "clue" to know that the answer was right. Without that the answer from @redfur was just as valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Garfield

Because

> Half of Garbage(gar) and a field.

Comment: oh damn of course :)

Comment: Correct! Well done!

Answer (score 5):

Could it be

> Garland, (decoration thingy).

Based on

> The first picture seems to be "Garbage", and since it's a half of the picture, it would map to "Gar". The second picture is "land"!

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'll give this a shot:
1st image:

> trash, verb, to break

2nd image:

> windy landscape

Answer:

> Breaking Wind :)

Comment: Come to think of it, the images look a bit artsy-fartsy ...

Comment: Not quite. Nice try!

Answer (score 3):

> This is all I could come up with:  Trashing the landscape?

Comment: Not quite. Nice try!